# How to Sum Multiple Rows for same value in Excel using a macro with data manipulation

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I am very novice when it comes to macros and need your help. I need help creating a macro to sum multiple rows for same value into one cell. Here is what I am looking for

```
Project #  Impacted LOB  Hrs

1111       Operation     500
1111       Operation-IT  1000
1111       Marketing     5000
1111       Marketing-IT  1000  
2222       Operation- IT 100
2222       Operation     200
2222       Marketing     200
2222       Marketing-IT  5000
```

What I am expecting is the following:

```
PROJECT   IT HOURS NON IT HOURS
1111       2000    5500
2222       5100    400
```

Below the code I have but the problem is I am not getting one row for each project with totals

```
Sub First_Macro()
'Dont display delete button:
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'************ VARIABLES ****************
    'Starting row to analyze:
    StartRow = 5

    'Total rows to analyze:
    NumCols = 80000

    'New worksheet name:
    Dim New_Worksheet_Name As String
    New_Worksheet_Name = "CCB PPL EXTRACT"

    'CCB PPL Extract worksheet name:
    Dim Plan_Worksheet_Name As String
    Plan_Worksheet_Name = "PPL Project Estimates"

     'New worksheet for summary:Total Summary sheet with graph
    Dim New_Worksheet_Summary_Name As String
    New_Worksheet_Summary_Name = "Analyze HRSs Summary"

'*********end variables********
Dim sh As Worksheet, flg As Boolean
'Add Concept Vs. Requirements worksheet:

flg = False
For Each sh In Worksheets
    If sh.Name Like New_Worksheet_Name Then flg = True: Exit For
    'If sh.Name Like BE_Worksheet_Name Then flg = True: Exit For
Next
If flg = True Then
    Sheets(New_Worksheet_Name).Delete
End If
Dim NEW_WS As Worksheet
Set NEW_WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
     ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
NEW_WS.Name = New_Worksheet_Name

Dim NEW_SUM_WS As Worksheet
Set NEW_SUM_WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
     ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
NEW_SUM_WS.Name = New_Worksheet_Summary_Name

'GET DATA:
Dim Plan_WS As Worksheet
Set Plan_WS = Worksheets(Plan_Worksheet_Name)
'Set headers in new worksheet:
NEW_WS.Cells(1, 1).Value = "DM ID                                                                                           "
NEW_WS.Cells(1, 2).Value = "PROJECT TITLE"
NEW_WS.Cells(1, 3).Value = "STATUS"
NEW_WS.Cells(1, 4).Value = "IMPACTED LOB"
NEW_WS.Cells(1, 5).Value = "CONCEPT HRS"
NEW_WS.Cells(1, 6).Value = "REQUIREMENT HRS"
NEW_WS.Cells(1, 7).Value = "RELEASE DATE"

Dim DM_ID_Array(1 To 20000) As String
Dim DM_PROJECT_TITLE_Array(1 To 20000) As String
Dim DM_PROJECT_STATUS_Array(1 To 20000) As String
Dim DM_CONCEPT_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(1 To 20000) As String
Dim DM_REQ_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(1 To 20000) As String
Dim DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(1 To 20000) As String
Dim DM_REQ_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(1 To 20000) As String
Dim DM_CONCEPT_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(1 To 20000) As String
Dim DM_REQ_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(1 To 20000) As String
Dim DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(1 To 20000) As String
Dim DM_REQ_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(1 To 20000) As String
Dim DM_ID_Index As Long
DM_ID_Index = 0

'Loop through rows in colum:
Dim j As Long
j = 1
h = 2
prev_dm_id = Plan_WS.Cells(StartRow, 1).Value
For i = StartRow To NumCols
    DM_ID = Plan_WS.Cells(i, 1).Value
    PROJECT_TITLE = Plan_WS.Cells(i, 6).Value
    Status = Plan_WS.Cells(i, 7).Value
    lob = Plan_WS.Cells(i, 10).Value
    concept_hrs = Plan_WS.Cells(i, 17).Value
    req_hrs = Plan_WS.Cells(i, 19).Value
    release_date = Plan_WS.Cells(i, 39).Value
    If Status = "15. Commitment Complete" Then
        NEW_WS.Cells(h, 1).Value = DM_ID
        NEW_WS.Cells(h, 2).Value = PROJECT_TITLE
        NEW_WS.Cells(h, 3).Value = Status
        NEW_WS.Cells(h, 4).Value = lob
        NEW_WS.Cells(h, 5).Value = concept_hrs
        NEW_WS.Cells(h, 6).Value = req_hrs
        NEW_WS.Cells(h, 7).Value = release_date

        If DM_ID = prev_dm_id Then
            prev_dm_id = DM_ID
            DM_ID_Index = DM_ID_Index + 1
            DM_ID_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_ID
            DM_PROJECT_TITLE_Array(DM_ID_Index) = PROJECT_TITLE
            DM_PROJECT_STATUS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = Status
            DM_CONCEPT_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = 0
            DM_REQ_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = 0
            DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = 0
            DM_REQ_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = 0
            DM_CONCEPT_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = 0
            DM_REQ_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = 0
            DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = 0
            DM_REQ_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = 0
            '*****************************************************
            If lob = "Auto Finance" Then
             DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + concept_hrs
             DM_REQ_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_REQ_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + req_hrs
            End If
            If lob = "Auto Finance IT" Then
              DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + concept_hrs
              DM_REQ_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_REQ_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + req_hrs
            End If
            If lob = "CARD Business" Then
              DM_CONCEPT_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_CONCEPT_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_CONCEPT_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + concept_hrs
              DM_REQ_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_REQ_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + req_hrs
            End If
            If lob = "CARD Canada Business" Then
              DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + concept_hrs
              DM_REQ_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_REQ_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + req_hrs
            End If
            If lob = "CARD Canada IT" Then
              DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + concept_hrs
              DM_REQ_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_REQ_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + req_hrs
            End If
            If lob = "CARD Commercial Card IT" Then
              DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + concept_hrs
              DM_REQ_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_REQ_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + req_hrs
            End If
            If lob = "CARD Technology" Then
              DM_CONCEPT_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_CONCEPT_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + concept_hrs
              DM_REQ_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_REQ_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + req_hrs
            End If
            If lob = "CBB TECHNOLOGY" Then
              DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + concept_hrs
              DM_REQ_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_REQ_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + req_hrs
            End If
            If lob = "CCB Architecture, Data, Quality & Chief Development Office" Then
              DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + concept_hrs
              DM_REQ_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_REQ_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + req_hrs

            End If
            If lob = "CCB Operations" Then
              DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + concept_hrs
              DM_REQ_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_REQ_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + req_hrs
            End If
            If lob = "CCB Risk Management" Then
              DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + concept_hrs
              DM_REQ_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_REQ_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + req_hrs
            End If
            If lob = "CHASE WEALTH MGMT" Then
              DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + concept_hrs
              DM_REQ_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_REQ_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + req_hrs
            End If
            If lob = "Commerce Solutions" Then
              DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + concept_hrs
              DM_REQ_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_REQ_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + req_hrs
            End If
            If lob = "Commerce Solutions Technology" Then
              DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + concept_hrs
              DM_REQ_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_REQ_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + req_hrs
            End If
            If lob = "CONSUMER AND COMMUNITY BANKING" Then
              DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + concept_hrs
              DM_REQ_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_REQ_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + req_hrs
            End If
            If lob = "CONSUMER BANKING" Then
              DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + concept_hrs
              DM_REQ_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_REQ_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + req_hrs
            End If
            If lob = "CORPORATE SECTOR" Then
              DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + concept_hrs
              DM_REQ_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_REQ_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + req_hrs
            End If
            If lob = "Digital" Then
               DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + concept_hrs
               DM_REQ_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_REQ_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + req_hrs
            End If
            If lob = "Digital Technology" Then
              DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + concept_hrs
              DM_REQ_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_REQ_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + req_hrs
            End If
            If lob = "Infrastructure Risk and Controls" Then
              DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + concept_hrs
              DM_REQ_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_REQ_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + req_hrs
            End If
            If lob = "Marketing Services" Then
              DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + concept_hrs
              DM_REQ_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_REQ_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + req_hrs
            End If
            If lob = "Mortgage Banking" Then
              DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + concept_hrs
              DM_REQ_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_REQ_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + req_hrs
            End If
            If lob = "Mortgage Banking Technology" Then
              DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + concept_hrs
              DM_REQ_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_REQ_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + req_hrs
            End If
            If lob = "OPERATIONS TECHNOLOGY" Then
              DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + concept_hrs
              DM_REQ_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_REQ_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + req_hrs
            End If
            If lob = "Student Loans" Then
              DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + concept_hrs
              DM_REQ_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_REQ_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + req_hrs
            End If
            If lob = "Student Loans IT" Then
              DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + concept_hrs
              DM_REQ_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) = DM_REQ_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(DM_ID_Index) + req_hrs
            End If
         End If
End If


    h = h + 1
'End If
Next
'summarize columns
NEW_SUM_WS.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Committed Totals by DM ID"
NEW_SUM_WS.Cells(2, 1).Value = "DM ID "
NEW_SUM_WS.Cells(2, 2).Value = "PROJECT TITLE"
NEW_SUM_WS.Cells(2, 3).Value = "STATUS"
NEW_SUM_WS.Cells(2, 4).Value = "CONCEPT-BUS HRS"
NEW_SUM_WS.Cells(2, 5).Value = "REQ-BUS HRS"
NEW_SUM_WS.Cells(2, 6).Value = "CONCEPT-CARD IT HRS"
NEW_SUM_WS.Cells(2, 7).Value = "REQ-CARD IT HRS"
NEW_SUM_WS.Cells(2, 8).Value = "CONCEPT-NON CARD IT HRS"
NEW_SUM_WS.Cells(2, 9).Value = "REQ-NON CARD IT HRS"
NEW_SUM_WS.Cells(2, 10).Value = "CONCEPT-NON CARD BUS HRS"
NEW_SUM_WS.Cells(2, 11).Value = "REQ-NON CARD BUS HRS"
NEW_SUM_WS.Cells(2, 12).Value = "COMMITMENT DATE"

 Dim jj As Long
jj = 1
For i = 1 To UBound(DM_ID_Array)
    If Len(DM_ID_Array(i)) Then
        NEW_SUM_WS.Cells((2 + i), 1).Value = DM_ID_Array(i)
        NEW_SUM_WS.Cells((2 + i), 2).Value = DM_PROJECT_TITLE_Array(i)
        NEW_SUM_WS.Cells((2 + i), 3).Value = DM_PROJECT_STATUS_Array(i)
        NEW_SUM_WS.Cells((2 + i), 4).Value = DM_CONCEPT_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(i)
        NEW_SUM_WS.Cells((2 + i), 5).Value = DM_REQ_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(i)
        NEW_SUM_WS.Cells((2 + i), 6).Value = DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(i)
        NEW_SUM_WS.Cells((2 + i), 7).Value = DM_REQ_NON_CARD_IT_TOTAL_HRS_Array(i)
        NEW_SUM_WS.Cells((2 + i), 8).Value = DM_CONCEPT_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(i)
        NEW_SUM_WS.Cells((2 + i), 9).Value = DM_REQ_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(i)
        NEW_SUM_WS.Cells((2 + i), 10).Value = DM_CONCEPT_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(i)
        NEW_SUM_WS.Cells((2 + i), 11).Value = DM_REQ_NON_CARD_BUS_TOTAL_HRS_Array(i)
        jj = jj + 1
    End If
 Next i
 End Sub
```

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Build helper column then use `sumifs`.

Comment: You'll need to put a bit more work in to get a response from people but a good place to start would be, as @findwindow said, a `SUMIFS` function. You could even do it without a macro if there aren't many `Project #`s. Refer to this link if you need help with `SUMIFS`: (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b

Comment: Thanks Scott. I am not familiar with how to build helper column either

Comment: I actually have over 20000 rows for project id . I need to break down the hours into 6 different categories based on LOB value. That is why I need a macro I guess

Comment: This can be done with Array Formulas, but would get long on the calculations,  vba is the way to go.  That being said, SO is not a code for me service.  If you have code that you have tried that is not working we will help find the problem and fix it.  Please post any attempt you have done in the original post using the edit selection.

Answer (score 2):

Use this formula in column D: `=if(not(iserr(find("IT", $B2, 1))),"IT HOURS","NON IT HOURS")`

[image]

Highlight your entire table, go to INSERT > PIVOT TABLE
It will add a new sheet with a Pivot table to your workbook.
With the Pivot table options, add Project to row labels, Type to column labels, and Hrs to values (make a sum).

[image]

This should do the sums automatically based on the breakdown by type that you defined.

Comment: This is true. Thanks for that. Assuming each string has "IT" in it, I have added a way to label each row as IT. After doing that, it would then be easy to use a pivot table. See my edits.

Comment: did you add a pivot table to your workbook? see my edits above.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an SQL solution as this is a classic conditional aggregate query. MS Excel can run SQL on its own workbook using the Windows built-in Jet/ACE SQL Engine (.dll file) which is available to all MS Office products, not just a restricted technology for Excel's database sibling, MS Access. Below is the SQL query embedded as string in VBA macro.

**SQL** Query *(using wildcard match on "IT"; incorporate for other searches)*

```
SELECT [Project #]
       SUM(IIF([Impacted LOB] LIKE '%Operation%', 
               [Hrs], NULL)) As [IT HOURS]
       SUM(IIF([Impacted LOB] NOT LIKE '%-IT%', 
               [Hrs], NULL)) As [NON IT HOURS]
FROM DataTable
GROUP BY [Project #];
```

**Worksheet Setup** *(structure data much like database tables with columns in first row and same data types; create DATA and RESULTS tabs and leave latter to be populated with macro)*

[image: Data Worksheet Tab]
[image: Results]

**VBA** Macro *(another connection string commented out)*

```
Sub RunSQL()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    Dim conn As Object, rst As Object
    Dim strConnection As String, strSQL As String
    Dim i As Integer, fld As Object

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    ' Hard code database location and name
'    strConnection = "DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" _
'                      & "DBQ=C:\Path\To\Workbook.xlsm;"
    strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
                       & "Data Source='C:\Path\To\Workbook.xlsm;" _
                       & "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;"";"

    strSQL = "SELECT [DATA$].[Project #], " _
              & "     SUM(IIF([DATA$].[Impacted LOB] Like '%Operation%', [DATA$].[Hrs], NULL)) As [IT HOURS]," _
              & "     SUM(IIF([DATA$].[Impacted LOB] NOT LIKE '%-IT%', [DATA$].[Hrs], NULL)) As [NON IT HOURS]" _
              & " FROM [DATA$] " _
              & " GROUP BY [DATA$].[Project #];"

    ' Open the db connection
    conn.Open strConnection
    rst.Open strSQL, conn

    ' column headers
    i = 0
    Worksheets("RESULTS").Activate
    Worksheets("RESULTS").Range("A1").Activate
    For Each fld In rst.Fields
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, i) = fld.Name
        i = i + 1
    Next fld

    ' data rows
    Worksheets("RESULTS").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst

    rst.Close
    conn.Close

    MsgBox "Successfully ran SQL query!", vbInformation
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " = " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```